# Is there a way to add to my html the "chrome.extension" library/reference/class

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon

When i'm looking in a Chrome extension plugin there is a class or something like that called `Chrome.extension`

For example:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, response) {
  if (request.msg == 'page_capturable') {
    $('tip').style.display = 'none';
    $('capture........
    ........................
    ........................
```

[The URL for the example](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/source/browse/trunk/src/popup.js)

As you see there are several functions inside this chrome.extension like  `onRequest`,`getBackgroundPage()` and others...

I checked with Firefox browser and it support this **chrome.extension** too...

I want to try and add this class to my html files, to enabled this functions with JavaScript or something a like

I'm going to try and use it inside **Internet explorer**.

Is there someone that can light me on this topic?
maybe  a URL or the package it self?

**BTW**: I took google chrome extension and manage to convert it to Firefox
This is my proof that Firefox support this chrome.extension thing
[Chrome on Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the chrome.extension library. google share it as JS file

Most of the function are there and there are several empty functions :(

Hope that it will help someone...

**http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js**